# How to disable the cross and other touch events in ios-charts?

Tags: ios, ios-charts

i have a Line Chart view in my iOS app.

```
@IBOutlet weak var lineChartView: LineChartView!
```

the zooming and touching is enabled. I do not let the user do anything in the chart, even selecting is not allowed.

I tried:

```
self.lineChartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false
self.lineChartView.dragEnabled = false
self.lineChartView.dragDecelerationEnabled = false
```

but without any luck. I can still touch the graph and see the cross. I even can pinch to zoom the graph.

How can i turn this behaviour off?+

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Doh! 
in storyboard I can disable "User Interaction Enabled".

that do the trick.

Comment: .userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone would like it to still drag but only disable zooming, you can try
`self.lineChart.setScaleEnabled(false)`

Comment: `self.setScaleEnabled(false)` worked for me! I could complete my need using the method with `self.pinchZoomEnabled = false` without using UIView method: `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` which prevents all user interaction under the children views

Answer (score 8):

The accepted solution didn't work for my `barChartView` for some reason.

Instead, setting `barChartView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` did the trick.

So, for the OP, the following should work `self.lineChartView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to still have the interactive chart Try these:

```
chartView.dragXEnabled = false
chartView.dragYEnabled = false
chartView.scaleXEnabled = false
chartView.scaleYEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used

```
dataSet.highlightColor = .clear
```